# Bind combo box from table with two columns

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

How can I join this data, or there's a better way?

Example when data joined `accountID - accountname`

```
          public void BindData()
          {
                cn.Open();
                string strCmd = "select accountID from MsAccount";
                string strCmd2 = "select accountName from MsAccount";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, cn);
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strCmd2, cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd2, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                da2.Fill(dt2);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "AccountID";
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt2;

                comboBox1.ValueMember =  "accountName";

                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "AccountID"+ "-"+"accountName";<<OUTPUT that i need
                //comboBox1.DisplayMember = "accountName";

                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                comboBox2.Enabled = true;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
           }
```

Comment: what is the client ? Windows form ?

Comment: Why are you binding 2 sources one after another? `dt` will be replaced as you bind `dt2`.

Comment: yes, it's windows form.
i bind two sources like that because i don't understand how to join it properly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
   SELECT 
         accountID, 
         (CAST(accountID AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+accountName) AS accountName 
    FROM 
         MsAccount
```

Instead calling them seperately.

```
public void BindData()
          {
                cn.Open();
                string strCmd = "SELECT accountID, (CAST(accountID AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+accountName) AS accountName FROM MsAccount";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "accountID";
                comboBox1.DisplayMember =  "accountName";
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                cn.Close();
           }
```